# ¿Qué significa “nudos de enfardelar”?

Tags: significado, literatura

Estaba leyendo [*El amor en los tiempos del cólera*](https://www.wattpad.com/456326612-el-amor-en-los-tiempos-del-c%C3%B3lera-cap%C3%ADtulo-1) de García Márquez. La siguiente frase me resulta difícil de entender:

> Tenía las pupilas diáfanas, la barba y los cabellos amarillentos, y el vientre atravesado por una cicatriz antigua cosida con ***nudos de enfardelar***.

¿Qué significa ***nudos de enfardelar*** en este contexto? ¿Tiene algo que ver con [fardeles](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fardel) o [con fardos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paca_de_paja)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Un fardo es un paquete de ropa o de paja, un bulto atado de forma tosca, por lo general para ser transportado. El que hace un fardo de ropa no tiene especial cuidado en que el nudo quede hermoso, sino en que el nudo sea resistente, así no se vea muy bonito.

Por el contrario, un cirujano trata de que sus costuras sean muy finas y cada costura se llama punto. Cuando una persona tiene una herida que requiere ser cosida, se dice que requiere puntos. Cuanto más larga y profunda sea la herida, más puntos requiere. Decimos que un cirujano o en general cualquier doctor, tiene buena mano, si cuando se retiran los puntos, la cicatriz es lo menos notoria posible.

Ahora imaginemos que al ver una cicatriz, nos viene a la mente que fue cosida, no con puntos, sino con nudos de enfardelar.

Comment: Muy bien explicado, Javier. Bienvenido al sitio

Answer (score 5):

[*Enfardelar*](https://dle.rae.es/enfardelar) es un verbo:

> 1. tr. Hacer [fardeles](https://dle.rae.es/fardel#7ffpEDT) (‖ sacos o talegas).
>
> 2. tr. [enfardar](https://dle.rae.es/enfardar#6e9UaP1).

Donde *fardel* es un [*fardo*](https://dle.rae.es/fardo#7fjbd7q) grande. Por tanto, cuando habla de *nudos de enfardelar* García Márquez seguramente se refería a los nudos que se usan a la hora de hacer fardeles. Es fácil pensar que si alguien tiene *una cicatriz antigua cosida con nudos de enfardelar* seguramente es alguien a quien le hicieron esta "cirugía" con el único material que tuvieron a mano, ya sea por pobreza o por situación grave (mirando un fragmento más extenso del libro vemos que la persona muerta era inválido de guerra).

Comment: Más que el material concreto empleado, yo creo que el texto se refiere a que la "cirugía" no se hizo con cuidado o pericia suficiente, que el resultado fue muy tosco. En mi opinión, la pobreza o no del aludido actualmente no queda implícita en el texto extractado.

Comment: Bien visto, @RubioRic. No lo sé. Me bajé el capítulo al que pertenece este fragmento para así tener más contexto, esta noche lo leo con calma y vuelvo a comentar.

Comment: @RubioRic estuve leyendo el fragmento de https://www.megustaleer.com/libros/el-amor-en-los-tiempos-del-clera/MES-007814/fragmento y define al hombre muerto como _El refugiado antillano Jeremiah de Saint-Amour, inválido de guerra (...) Su torso y sus brazos tenían una envergadura de galeote por el trabajo de las muletas, pero sus piernas inermes parecían de huérfano_. Te doy la razón en que lo de pobre no es inherente, sino más bien (y gracias al fragmento más extenso) pertenece a alguien cosido en un trance complicado (guerra) y cuerpo bastante perjudicado por la edad y el clima tropical.

Comment: Nada, hombre. Un pequeño matiz. La respuesta ya me parecía válida. Gracias por mirarlo!